Different values of \hsize and \vsize with PlainTeX?
The following example shows, that TeX displays different values of \hsize and \vsize .
Can someone explain, why this happens??
%{
    {\bf First}%
    
    Some text.
    
    \hsize=469.0pt%
    %
    \the\hsize
    
    \vsize=643.0pt%
    %
    \the\vsize%
     %  
     %}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    {\bf Second}%
    
    Some text.
    
     %
    \hsize=469.0pt%
    \the\hsize
    
     \vsize=643.0pt%
    \the\vsize%  
    \bye


Try \hsize=469.0pt\relax and so on, and see what you get.

@mickep It works.

When you do
\hsize=469pt\the\hsize

(which is equivalent to your code), TeX looks for a space after the keyword pt expanding tokens. Thus \the\hsize is expanded and eventually prints the value that was stored earlier, which isn't 469pt, because the assignment of the new value hasn't yet been finalized at the time \the is expanded.
Note that all of your % are either superfluous or harmful.
Some text

\the\hsize

\the\vsize

\vskip\baselineskip

{\bf First}

Some text.

\hsize=469.0pt
\the\hsize

\vsize=643.0pt
\the\vsize

\vskip\baselineskip
{\bf Second}

Some text.

\hsize=469.0pt
\the\hsize

\vsize=643.0pt
\the\vsize

\bye


This is one of the reasons why LaTeX defines \setlength, which avoids the issue as it adds \relax after the second argument, thereby stopping the expansion TeX tries.
Note that a space found after pt in the context of an assignment will be ignored.

This is weird:  "\hsize=469.0pt\the\hsize" gives 469.75499 pt
"\hsize=469.0pt\the\hsize " gives 469.0 pt. This may be, because the \hsize is not expanded at the right time. Is there a command like "\expandnow" or similar?

@MBE what do you want to expand? at the risk of being obliterated by egreg, \hsize isn't a macro.

@mbe Just type \hsize=469pt \the\hsize (note the space). I’m not sure what you’re asking for, though

Sometimes it is only the language: "Note that a space found after pt in the context of an assignment will be ignored." It is not "ignored", but not "typed".

@MBE Knuth says that “it doesn't get through” and uses “ignored” elsewhere.

@egreg
I am asking  why the same, not by a single sign differing codes put out different values.
